# Woocommerce - Add HTML around Product description

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

How can I add HTML around the product description?

Exactly around the `Product Description` heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the default WooCommerce description template by copying the description template **`description.php`** from WooCommerce templates to **`/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/`** in your active theme folder.

Refer [WooCommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) to understand how to overwrite WooCommerce default template files.